# Display content in the card when hover

Tags: html, css, hover, styles

I have a card item as you see in the picture, opacity is 0.5:
[image]

When I hover I want to display some information on it like in the picture again:
[image]

So here is my example;

```css
.card-img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: calc(0.3rem - 0px);
}

.card-img-top {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 32px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.card-img-top:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="card">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="card-img-top img-raised" src="img/banner-1.png" alt="Open Project 1">
      <div class="banner-content">
        Description
      </div>
      <a class="mb-2 mt-2 text-center small-xl" href="#">Check More Details</a>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

So what I am trying to achieve in this example, when I hover I want to display Description (banner-content) and I want to set the opacity to 1 which I am already doing.

Comment: when you hover the img you want to show div.banner-content? is this div hidden ?

Comment: Yes in the beginning banner-content is hidden. I want it to be shown when it has hovered.

Comment: Investigate the sibling selector + when you hover on the img you can also select its immediate sibling and set it to display block, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `+` selector wicth select the adjacent sibling. More on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)

```css
.card{
  position:relative;
}
.card-img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width:150px;
  border-radius: calc(0.3rem - 0px);
  
}

.card-img-top {
  border-radius: 32px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width:150px;
}

.card-img-top:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.banner-content{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  display:none;
}

.card-img-top:hover + .banner-content{display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="card">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="card-img-top img-raised" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="Open Project 1">
      <div class="banner-content">
        Description
      </div>
      <a class="mb-2 mt-2 text-center small-xl" href="#">Check More Details</a>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a **Adjacent Sibling Selector** when you hover on `img` and `display` the content .

`+` is used here which selects the first `.banner-content` element that is placed immediately after `.card-img-top` element .
[Find more info here about combinators](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp)

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
}

.banner-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  display:none;
}

.card-img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: calc(0.3rem - 0px);
}

.card-img-top {
  width: 400px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius: 32px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.card-img-top:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.card-img-top:hover + .banner-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="card">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="card-img-top img-raised" src="https://pixy.org/src/477/4774988.jpg" alt="Open Project 1">
      <div class="banner-content">
        I am a new coder.<br> Happy to meet : )

      </div><br>
      <a class="mb-2 mt-2 text-center small-xl" href="#">Check More Details</a>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** I make a `.top-layout` class with `opacity: 0` to keep it hide by default.

**Step 2:** Use `.card:hover .top-layout` selector in CSS to set what style you want when the card item is hover.

```css
.card {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: calc(0.3rem - 0px);
}

.card:hover .top-layout {
  opacity: 0.5 !important;
}

.top-layout {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.card-img-top {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 32px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="card">
    <a href="#">
      <img class="card-img-top img-raised" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/comic-colorful-frame-background_52683-71995.jpg" alt="Open Project 1">
      <div class="top-layout">
        <div class="banner-content">
          Description
        </div>
        <a class="mb-2 mt-2 text-center small-xl" href="#">Check More Details</a>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```